# Custom PHTML file not loading via the XML

Tags: theme, layout

I am trying to figure out why the `checkout/cart/header.phtml` is not loading when I am calling it from the xml file. This is a custom xml file called `beckin_minicart.xml`. Everything loads just fine except the phtml file. Do you see what I am doing wrong here?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout>

    <default>

        <reference name="head">
         <action method="addJs" ifconfig="minicart/settings/enable"><script>minicart/jquery-1.8.3.js</script></action>
         <action method="addJs" ifconfig="minicart/settings/enable"><script>minicart/cartdropdown.js</script></action>
             <action method="addCss" block="head" ifconfig="minicart/settings/enable"><template>css/minicart/minicart.css</template></action>
        </reference>



    <reference name="header">

        <!-- Quick Cart Dropdown -->
            <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="minicart" template="checkout/cart/header.phtml">
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
        </block>

        </reference>

    <reference name="top.links">
        <remove name="checkout_cart_link"/>
    </reference>

        <remove name="left.permanent.callout"/>
        <remove name="right.permanent.callout"/>
        <remove name="paypal.partner.right.logo"/>
        <remove name="cart_sidebar"/>

    </default>

</layout>
```

Comment: Not sure if this changes something but add an `as` attribute on the block element: `block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="minicart" as="minicart" template="checkout/cart/header.phtml">...</block>`

Comment: Thanks! Just tried that but still no luck. Everything in the layout executes except loading that file. Not sure if it makes any difference but this is a new install and is located in the `base/default` folder?

Comment: Do you see anything in the var/log folder related to this? (assuming you have the logging activated).

Comment: @tech0925 What makes you think the template isn't being loaded? (Alternate question — what code is in your custom `checkout/cart/header.phtml` template?)

Comment: Hello @Alan. Because the HTML contained in the `header.phtml` file is not in the loaded HTML. @Marius, I actually haven't checked the logs. Maybe that will tell me something.

Answer (score 1):

I'm still not 100% sure what you're asking, but looking at your code

```
<reference name="header">

    <!-- Quick Cart Dropdown -->
        <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="minicart" template="checkout/cart/header.phtml">
    <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
        <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
    </block>

    </reference>
```

Here you're adding a new block named `minicart` to the `header` block.  However, the `header` block is a **template** block, which means it does not automatically render blocks that have been added to it.  You'd need to have a

```
$this->getChildHtml('minicart');
```

In your

```
page/html/header.phtml
```

template.